# UIImagePickerController white screen

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, uiimagepickercontroller

I have been searching SO to resolve this but I have not found anything that solves my issue.
So here is the problem:

My app sometimes loads a white screen when it is supposed to load the UIImagePickerController on a button touch.

This is a memory issue as this only occurs when a memory warning fires. 
It seems like the memory-warning releases the original viewcontroller(the one that loads the imagepicker) on transition between the two viewcontrollers.

This leads to not having the original viewcontroller and not loading the UIImagePickerController(as it has no parent) in other words a white screen.

Also worth mentioning is that i programatically fired memory warnings before and after "presenting" the vc ant it does not reproduce the issue:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] _performMemoryWarning];
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] _performMemoryWarning];
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: First of all you'll have to look into using less memory, check if you clean up all your resources. What happens if you dismiss the UIImagePickerController in didReceiveMemoryWarning?

Comment: The thing is that the original vc does not receive any memory warnings. Any ideas how to reproduce the scenario?

Comment: In the simulator you can do Hardware -> Simulate Memory Warning

Comment: yes i know but how to do it in the transition where i suspect it occurs... I've been able to crash the app due to low memory but never i havent reproduced the whitescreen. Thanks for the help btw!

Answer (score 0):

I would then:

1. If you can check directly: check in `viewWillAppear` if the
   `UIImagePicker` is loaded and load it manually if needed.
2. If you cannot check it directly: Override the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method in your custom UIViewController subclass. Set it this function a boolean like `imagePickerNeedsReload = YES` and check this flag in `viewWillAppear`, and them perform 1.

Comment: The thing is that the original vc does not receive any memory warnings. Any ideas how to reproduce the scenario?

Comment: Write some short app which takes a tons of memory within i.e. 20 seconds, and fire it just before yours. You'll get memory warning for sure.

Comment: You may wnt to track down calls chain for memory warning from application delegate down to view controllers to check if event propagation is properly set and all vc's gets the warning